# Exponential problems

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation, exponential-function

> A ship embarked on a long voyage. At the start of the voyage, there were 300 ants in the cargo hold of the ship. One week into the voyage, there were 600 ants. Suppose the population of ants is an exponential function of time.
>   There also was an exponentially-growing population of anteaters on board. At the start of the voyage there were 19 anteaters, and the population of anteaters doubled every 2.4 weeks. How long into the voyage were there 200 ants per anteater?

So I got the exponential equation for ants to be $y=300(2^{x\text{ weeks}})$. So for the anteaters I got $y=19(2^{x/2.4})$. So if I set the $2$ equations equal to each other and solve I get $0.416666667$ and  every other way I try to do this problem I get confused and get weird numbers. The sample prob is: ants $= 500 (1.6^x)$ and anteaters $= 18(2^{x.2.8})$ and the answer was $8.617$ weeks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:  Your equations for ants and anteaters are correct, but you should not use the same variable on the left.  Let $y$ be the number of ants at time $x$ (measured in weeks), then you are right that $y=300 \cdot 2^x$ and if $z$ is the number of anteaters you have $z=19 \cdot 2^{x/2.4}$.  Now you are asked for the time when $y=200z$, so set those equal.

Comment: Oh alright, I just have one question. so i get: 300(2^x)=200(19(2^2.4)) and if i divide 30o by 200 then that by 19 i get 0.07894736(2^x)=2^(x/24). So if i take ln on both sides to find x, am i taking the ln of 0.07089 also?

Comment: if I do, i get an answer of 6.27. Im not sure if that is correct

Comment: [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=300+*2%5Ex%3D200*19*2%5E%28x%2F2.4%29) gives about $6.27937$, which doesn't round to your value, but is very close.